# Offset a marker on Mapbox

Tags: javascript, three.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

My map markers look like this:

[image: map]

As you can see, the center of the blue markers is what is actually on my desired coordinates, is there a way to offset the markers just a bit up so the tip of the marker sits on my exact point, instead of being centered?

My code for the markers is pretty standard, like on the mapbox documentation. Looks like this:

```js
await nodeList.map((node) => {
    map.addSource(node.name, {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': {
            'type': 'FeatureCollection',
            'features': [{
                'type': 'Feature',
                'geometry': {
                    'type': 'Point',
                    'coordinates': [node.longitude, node.latitude]
                },
                'properties': {}
            }]
        }
    });
    map.addLayer({
        'id': node.name,
        'type': 'symbol',
        'source': node.name,
        'layout': {
            'icon-image': 'custom-marker',
            'text-offset': [0, 1.25],
            'text-anchor': 'top'
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#symbol) of symbol layers, you’ll find there’s an option to define an `icon-anchor` attribute as a string indicating the part of the Marker that should be positioned closest to the coordinate set. Options are  'center' ,  'top' , 'bottom' ,  'left' , 'right' ,  'top-left' , 'top-right' ,  'bottom-left' , and  'bottom-right'

The default value is 'center', so if you use `icon-anchor: bottom` in the options of your anchor it will position correctly.

```js
await nodeList.map((node) => {
    map.addSource(node.name, {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': {
            'type': 'FeatureCollection',
            'features': [{
                'type': 'Feature',
                'geometry': {
                    'type': 'Point',
                    'coordinates': [node.longitude, node.latitude]
                },
                'properties': {}
            }]
        }
    });
    map.addLayer({
        'id': node.name,
        'type': 'symbol',
        'source': node.name,
        'layout': {
            'icon-image': 'custom-marker',
            'icon-anchor': 'bottom',
            'text-offset': [0, 1.25],
            'text-anchor': 'top'
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already a layout option "icon-offset" in style definition of Mapbox GL. You can use it for basic styling or data driven styling.
AFAIK, you should define an image to be able to use. Below is an example usage taken from a React Mapbox GL app:

```
    <Source
      id="medya"
      type="geojson"
      data={filtered}
      generateId={true}
    />
    <Layer
      source="medya"
      id="medya"
      type="symbol"          
      layout={{
        "icon-image": "camera",
        "icon-offset": 0.2,
        "icon-size": 0.2,
        "icon-allow-overlap": true,
      }}          
    />
```